# OPENGL oppening error

Tags: opengl

im trying to open a new project for opengl but there is a error like bellow:
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglut.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

i think i did project setup well and i have all dll lib an h files in place.
code i tried is bellow:

```
#include<C:\Users\virtouso\Documents\Downloads\Compressed\freeglut\include\GL\glut.h>

void init()
{
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D(0,100,0,200);
}
void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2i(30,100);
glVertex2i(50,10);
glEnd();
glFlush();
}
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
glutInitWindowPosition(200,200);
glutCreateWindow("Line");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your library search path includes the folder that has freeglut.lib?

Comment: i fixed some directories but now there is this error:The program '[26212] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).